# gdb: call accessor methods on NSManagedObject subclass?

Tags: objective-c, ios, gdb

I have a class, Song, which subclasses NSManagedObject. I'm using GDB to try and figure out a problem I'm having, and am having a hard time calling an accessor on my class using gdb.

Song.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
```

Song.m:

```
@dynamic title;
```

In the debugger, I see the "title" field on the object, when I try to print the value using the accessor, which should be generated at runtime if I understand correctly, it gives me an error:

```
 (gdb) po aSong  <Song: 0x59188d0>
 (entity: Song; id: 0x59162d0
 <x-coredata://99BE63F8-840A-47B5-A259-BCD74E1811C4/Song/p2>
 ; data: {
     composers = "<relationship fault: 0x4d62f30 'composers'>";
     dateCreated = nil;
     songLists = "<relationship fault: 0x59243c0 'songLists'>";
     title = "cancel?"; })  
 (gdb) p aSong.title  There is no member named
 title.
 (gdb) p [aSong title]
 Target does not respond to this message selector.
```

Chances are I'm doing something really stupid here, but what am I doing wrong? Is there any way to introspect an object and see what messages it will respond to using GDB?

Comment: Have you tried `p aSong->title`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, this is how `gdb` behaves. Rather than asking the object whether it will respond to a selector, it seems to just look at the object's implementation either *now* or *at compile time* (I haven't worked out which yet). Because Core Data attributes are dealt with during the message forwarding process, the debugger doesn't believe that `NSManagedObject` will respond to the attribute selectors.

This is probably worth reporting as a bug to Apple, so they can fix the debugger.

Comment: thanks, I confirmed this with an NSLog statement (which I probably should have done to begin with).

Answer (score 26):

You can access dynamically generated properties in `gdb` using the `valueForKey:` method, as in `[aSong valueForKey:@"title"]`.  (This technique works for synthesized properties too, if you're a masochist, but really it only comes in handy when inspecting `NSManagedObject` and its subclasses.)